# Filter a list of dictionaries by a list of keys in Python3

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

How can I filter a list of dictionaries in Python3?

```
results = [{'name':'jason','email':'test1@example.com'},
           {'name':'mike','email':'test2@example.com'},
           {'name':'eric','email':'test3@example.com'}]

allowed_keys = ['name']
```

I thought I could do something like:

```
results2 = dict((k, v) for k,v, in results.items() if k in allowed_keys)
```

But I get this error:

```
>> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Will this be thread safe?

Comment: You have a *list*, not a dictionary, so no, there is no `items()` method on `results`. What are you filtering on here, names, emails?

Comment: And please keep it to **one** question per post. Chances are, whatever solution we can come up with, it is **not** going to be atomic.

Comment: Ah alright. I'd like to return a list of dictionaries that only contains the key "names"

Comment: @MartijnPieters I will ask a separate question for the separate part. Thanks.

Comment: You should be using a `set` or `frozenset` for `allowed_keys`. Membership test is `O(1)` on sets and `O(n)` on lists.

Comment: @IceArdor ah alright, thank you. how would this look if i check against a set instead of a list?

Comment: @ensnare It doesn't change how the code looks at all: you still use `if <whatever> in allowed_keys`. Using a `set` will just make that operation `O(1)` instead of `O(n)`.

Comment: @ensnare `allowed_keys = frozenset(['name'])` No other changes necessary

Answer (score 1):

Given your clarifying comment "I'd like to return a list of dictionaries that only contains the key 'names':

```
>>> [{k: d[k] for k in allowed_keys} for d in results]
[{'name': 'jason'}, {'name': 'mike'}, {'name': 'eric'}]
```

*Note:*  This solution assumes that all keys in `allowed_keys` are guaranteed to be in each dictionary in results.  If not, do this (but note that it is possible to end up with some empty dictionaries):

```
[{k: d[k] for k in allowed_keys if k in d} for d in results]
```

Comment: It's not necessary based on the example code, but you might want an `if k in d` at the end of the dict comprehension, so that an exception isn't thrown of one of the dicts in `results` doesn't contain one of the keys in `allowed_keys`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters:  Good point.  For now I assume OP meant `'name'` as shown in the example code.

Answer (score 0):

The one liner is a little messy, but here it is. 
In short, you forgot to add an outer loop to iterate through all dictionaries.

```
new_results = [dict((k, v) for k, v in d.items() if k in allowed_keys) for d in results]
```

Perhaps a more readable solution:

```
new_results = []
for d in results:
    new_d = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        if k in allowed_keys:
            new_d[k] = v
    new_results.append(new_d)
```